# How to continue to further train a pre-trained YOLOv8 model

Tags: python, machine-learning, object-detection, yolo

I've trained a YOLOv8 model for object detection with 4 classes on a custom dataset.

Now I want to train it to detect more classes by increasing my dataset.

Instead of training the model from the start can I further train it specifically on the new dataset?

Comment: Usually you would load the pre-trained weights from your first run before further training with your larger dataset. This process depends on the framework you use (e.g. in tensorflow you could save/load model checkpoints). But the overall process doesn't vary a lot over frameworks. Without more context it is pretty hard to give more specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

!CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 WANDB_MODE=dryrun yolo detect train resume data=/kaggle/working/newyolov8files/custom_original_datayolov8.yaml model=/kaggle/working/runs/detect/train/weights/last.pt epochs=1000 cache=True imgsz=640 batch=64 patience=100 optimizer=RAdam

as above code you can resume training or train over pre-trained model using "model=last.pt" of last trained model

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).